# How to make REMOTE_USER stick when set in PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I'm doing some custom authentication written in PHP and need to set the REMOTE_USER variable, and make it stick, for use in other applications on the web server.

I'm able to set the `REMOTE_USER` variable and display it in `$_SERVER`, and used `apache_setenv()`, but a `phpinfo()` call in a second page doesn't list the variable as being set.

The web server is Apache 2 with PHP 5.  Any thoughts?

Addendum:  An example situation would be I authenticate a user against a database table and set the `REMOTE_USER` variable for them and then send them via proxy to a second server, passing `REMOTE_USER` along the proxy, as described here for one system:

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/4.3.1/Admin/Usesinglesign-onwithSplunk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `$_SERVER`.  That variable is populated from the server hosting PHP, and isn't something you should be messing with.

What you're looking for is `$_SESSION`.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: Thanks, Brad, but I don't think that's quite what I'm looking for.  I need to set REMOTE_USER for use outside of PHP, even going so far as to pass it as a header through an AJP connection and such.  I'm starting to worry I might need deeper integration with Apache for this.  Have you done this, specifically?  REMOTE_USER should show up in phpinfo(), and is not when using the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: @Rob, That's not done at the PHP level of things.  What you need is a separate authentication plugin for Apache.  Your proxy suggestion also works, but is quite messy.  If your other applications are in PHP, just do this right and set up some sort of single-sign-on in each application.

Comment: @Rob, No, you're definitely in the right place.  You just need to post a new question.  Before you do though, I'd start looking at various single-sign-on options available.  OpenID and such.  There are many choices.  If you want to go the masochistic route, write an Apache mod.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/developer/